# How to use regex pattern as replacement

Tags: javascript, python, regex, string, pcre

I have a replacement string:

> `********is******ri****f******s**d******s****du****?`

and a search pattern:

```
([y\s]|[wh]|[apl]|[oo]|[mb])*
```

and replacement pattern:

```
*$2*
```

is it possible to find out what the original string was, or use the replacement pattern to reverse it?

Comment: So `********is******ri****f******s**d******s****du****` is the result of the replacement and you are looking for the original string?

Comment: If you cannot do it by hand (which you can't), your computer won't be able to do it neither. The only thing you can do is generate all possible original string, which would be a feces-load (countably infinite I guess).

Comment: So is this like a regex encryption or something? It's quite odd — I've never thought of using regex to encrypt something before.

Comment: This has nothing to do with encryption. The important part of encryption is that you can decrypt it with the appropriate key. Your example is just about information loss. It is like saying "replace each vowel with an X". You cannot undo this and it is not an encryption.

Comment: Is it like an anagram then?

Comment: This cannot be the string resulting from a replacement. Given your regex matches nothing as well, there should be not be any alpha characters next to each other. That is if its a global replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As there are many alternatives in the regex, there will not be only one result if you want to reverse the operation, for the regex contains these alternatives :

```
1st Alternative: [y\s]
[y\s] match a single character present in the list below
    y the literal character y (case sensitive)
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
2nd Alternative: [wh]
[wh] match a single character present in the list below
    wh a single character in the list wh literally (case sensitive)
3rd Alternative: [apl]
[apl] match a single character present in the list below
    apl a single character in the list apl literally (case sensitive)
4th Alternative: [oo]
[oo] match a single character present in the list below
    oo the literal character o (case sensitive)
5th Alternative: [mb]
[mb] match a single character present in the list below
    mb a single character in the list mb literally (case sensitive)
```

so you might be able to program a code to give you all the possible combinations(huge load), but not one result.
hope this helps.

Comment: 4.5259256e41 possibilities for that small string. Good luck OP!